# Apigee key management in Java

Tags: apigee, key-management

For our portal development, we have decided to use Apigee to expose the web service to the portal. For which currently I am storing the **API Key and Api URL** in the properties file of the project. Can anyone help with some pointers on how else can I save the API key apart from the properties file.

Any pointers will be helpful in this case.

Regards
Aswathy

Answer (score 0):

Typically the API key will be persisted by the the API consumer - usually an App of some kind. In case of Mobile Apps, each of them have an API Key or Client ID that is saved inside the app usually in some kind of secure data store. For other kinds of API consumers such as web apps the API Key may be persisted within a secure vault or an database that has some encryption features.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your web portal app resides on a secure machine inside your enterprise and that this machine is access restricted. If this is the case bare minimum security is taken care of
However, If the key is a high privilege key and you can access APIs with key alone(ie without a secret), it is not advisable to keep it in plain text.
You can
1. Encrypt and store it in the config file and decrypt at runtime
2. Encrypt and store in Database or other secure storage you use for storing credentials.